# Join query using three tables mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am having three tables p_c_n_details, supplier_details, pcn_type. I tried join query using these tables. But there is an error in group by.

My query:

```
SELECT pcn_type.name, p_c_n_details.SupplierName, COUNT(p_c_n_details.JPN_ID) 
FROM pcn_type LEFT OUTER JOIN p_c_n_details RIGHT OUTER JOIN supplier_details 
ON p_c_n_details.type = pcn_type.name AND p_c_n_details.SupplierName = 
supplier_details.SupplierName GROUP BY 
pcn_type.name,supplier_details.SupplierName;
```

pcn_type table:

```
id    |    name
-------------------------
1          Process Change
2          Design Change
3          EOL
```

supplier_details table:

```
id    |    SupplierName
------------------------
1          abc
2          def
3          ghi
```

p_c_n_details table:

```
id.   |    SupplierName    |    type           |    JPN_ID
1          abc                  Process Change      0023
2          abc                  Process Change      0024
3          abc                  Process Change      0025
4          abc                  Design Change       0026
5          abc                  Design Change       0027
6          def                  Process Change      0028
7          def                  Process Change      0029
8          def                  EOL                 0030
9          def                  EOL                 0031
```

Expecting Result:

```
name            |    supplier  |    total
------------------------------------------------------    
Process Change       abc            03
Design Change        abc            02
EOL                  abc             0
Process Change       def            02
Design Change        def             0
EOL                  def            02
```

Error I am getting:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'GROUP BY pcn_type.name,supplier_details.SupplierName LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

what i need to change in the query to rectify the error.

Comment: Note that nobody ever uses RIGHT JOIN. Just sayin'

Comment: Where are columns `SupplierName` and `JPN_ID` in p_c_n_details?

Comment: @skelwa, you are right I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use query like

```
Select pt.name  as name,  sd.SupplierName  as supplier,count(pd.id)
from pcn_type pt 
join   supplier_details sd 
left join   p_c_n_details pd on  pd.type = pt.name and pd.Suppliername = sd.SupplierName 
group by  pt.name,  sd.SupplierName 
order by  sd.SupplierName
```

OUTPUT:-
[image]

create the environment with table ans sql query where you can directly test the query. Please visit fiddle for more details http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d379c3/18

Answer (score 1):

There were mistakes in your query, check below updated query and compare with your old query:

```
SELECT
    pcn_type. NAME,
    p_c_n_details.SupplierName,
    COUNT(p_c_n_details.id)
FROM
    pcn_type
LEFT OUTER JOIN p_c_n_details ON p_c_n_details.type = pcn_type.name 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN supplier_details ON p_c_n_details.Suppliername = supplier_details.SupplierName
GROUP BY p_c_n_details.Suppliername, p_c_n_details.type;
```

Comment: Your query seems to be missing scenario  EOL , abc,0

Comment: Yes that Depends on data, if EOL data will be in table it will give in result.. I have provided general query.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `CROSS JOIN` *Cartesian product* to get `pcn_type.name` and `supplier_details.SupplierName`.

You seem to want to filter name, if it didn't exist in `p_c_n_details` table, write a subquery  condition in `where` to get the name to exist in`p_c_n_details`, then use `OUTER JOIN` and `COUNT`

```
CREATE TABLE pcn_type(
     id int,
     name varchar(50)
);


INSERT INTO pcn_type VALUES (1,'Process Change');
INSERT INTO pcn_type VALUES (2,'Design Change');
INSERT INTO pcn_type VALUES (3,'EOL');

CREATE TABLE supplier_details(
     id int,
     SupplierName varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO supplier_details VALUES (1,'abc');
INSERT INTO supplier_details VALUES (2,'def');
INSERT INTO supplier_details VALUES (3,'ghi');

CREATE TABLE p_c_n_details(
     id int,
     SupplierName varchar(50),
     type  varchar(50)
);


INSERT INTO p_c_n_details VALUES (1,'abc','Process Change');
INSERT INTO p_c_n_details VALUES (2,'abc','Process Change');
INSERT INTO p_c_n_details VALUES (3,'abc','Process Change');
INSERT INTO p_c_n_details VALUES (4,'abc','Design Change');
INSERT INTO p_c_n_details VALUES (5,'abc','Design Change');
INSERT INTO p_c_n_details VALUES (6,'def','Process Change');
INSERT INTO p_c_n_details VALUES (7,'def','Process Change');
INSERT INTO p_c_n_details VALUES (8,'def','EOL');
INSERT INTO p_c_n_details VALUES (9,'def','EOL');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t.name,t.SupplierName,COUNT(t1.id) total
from
(
  SELECT p.name,s.SupplierName 
  FROM   
    pcn_type p
  CROSS JOIN 
    supplier_details s
  WHERE 
    p.name IN (SELECT DISTINCT type FROM p_c_n_details) 
  AND
    s.SupplierName IN (SELECT DISTINCT SupplierName FROM p_c_n_details) 
) t
LEFT JOIN p_c_n_details t1 on t.name = t1.type and t.SupplierName = t1.SupplierName
GROUP BY  t.name,t.SupplierName
ORDER BY  t.SupplierName
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40a52c/11/0)**:

```
|           name | SupplierName | total |
|----------------|--------------|-------|
|            EOL |          abc |     0 |
| Process Change |          abc |     3 |
|  Design Change |          abc |     2 |
| Process Change |          def |     2 |
|            EOL |          def |     2 |
|  Design Change |          def |     0 |
```